# how to fix issue with AWS crawler that split comma inside double quotes and broke data catalog?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I'm setting a new crawler that execute on schedular but fail with double quotes that have commas inside

I search and find that OpenCSVSerDe lib is used to edit table details but I'm creating new tables and I want to know how to add some config that allows the crawler to generate data catalog correctly

If csv file have value like `"$3.62","4,406"` the data catalog should be

```
col0     col1
"$3.62"  "4,406"
```

but I'm getting:

```
col0     col1  col2
"$3.62"  "4    406"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a classifier (Crawlers → Classifiers) and assign it to the specific crawler (Crawler Info → Tags, description, security configuration, and classifiers).

I've tried the following settings and it works perfectly:
[image]

Comment: that was my first idea but don't works because the crawler keep using `LazySimpleSerDe` as serialization lib that have no support to double quoted string with commas inside.

Comment: Any luck solving this issue? I have the same problem and it is absolutely annoying...

Comment: @thijsvdp Any luck?  I changed the Serde serialization lib to OpenCSVSerde, and set the appropriate Serde parameters but Glue does not seem to notice these changes

Comment: This has solved my issue:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/glue-best-practices.html